# Is it to possible turn on do not disturb in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to turn on do not disturb through javascript code ?

Thanks

Comment: You're asking how to implement an entire feature. Those are not the kinds of questions you should be asking here. Instead, try to give a thorough explanation of what you have tried and where you got stuck. Only then can we really try to help you in your process of programming your feature.

Comment: I'm asking if it's possible!

Comment: In that case: Yes, depending on what you actually meant in your vague description of "DBD".

Comment: @JochemKuijpers  silence android/iphone. This mode can mute sound, stop vibration, and block visual disturbances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Neither iOS nor Android provide an API that gives access to the device's Do Not Disturb settings to JavaScript running in a webpage.